# How to combine multiple string vectors to one vector?

Tags: dolphindb

I use the following code to combine multiple string vectors:

```py
a=[]
b=["Ba", "Bb"]
c=["Ca", "Cb"]
all= a join b join c
all
```

But the result is not what I expect:

```py
(["Ba","Bb"],["Ca","Cb"])
```

The correct result should be ["Ba","Bb","Ca","Cb"]. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

```
b=["Ba", "Bb"]
c=["Ca", "Cb"]
all = a + b
print(all)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following script:

```py
all=array(STRING).append!(a).append!(b).append!(c)
```